# Get opponent user name google play games real time in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, multiplayer

I'm working on an app, it's a simple Realtime Multiplayer game using Google play games asset in Unity.

It's a 1 vs 1 game.

I would like to have access to the opponent user name.

So i can display it in the beginning of a game (just after Random Match, or Match with invitation is created).

I can access to the current player user name with this:

```
string PlayerUserName = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetSelf().DisplayName;
```

I tried this :

```
string PlayerUserName = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetSelf().ParticipantId;
```

It returns a huge line of random characters, and i think it's the own player id.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/779452/display-player-image-and-name-using-google.html) which stated that if you using [Google Play Games plugin for Unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) it allows you to access the Google Play Games API through Unity's [social interface](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html). You can use `Social.LoadUsers()` to load the player profile. Remember that the contents of the player profile are subject to privacy settings of the players. Then use `user.userName` to get the username based on their `userID`.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. I did like your comment `Participant Opponent = Social.LoadUsers();` and then `string OpponentUserName=Opponent.DisplayName;` . But i've got one error for the first line. I've got this : error CS1501: No overload for method "LoadUsers" takes "0" arguments. What did i miss?

Comment: It means that the method "LoadUsers" needs arguments. You may refer with these: [1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/954225/error-cs1501-no-overload-for-method.html) and [2](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/need-help-with-error-cs1501-no-overload-for-method-standardblock-takes-9-arguments.260560/).

Answer (score 0):

its too late to replay .but it may help others......

```
string current_player_id = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetSelf ().ParticipantId;
Participant p = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetParticipant (current_player_id);

List participants = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetConnectedParticipants();
string player1_id = participants [0].ParticipantId;
Participant p1 = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetParticipant (player1_id);
string player2_id = participants [1].ParticipantId;
Participant p1 = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetParticipant (player2_id);
if (p1.ParticipantId== p.ParticipantId) {
 opponentname.text = p2.DisplayName;
} else if (p2.ParticipantId== p.ParticipantId)
{
PlayerName.text = p1.DisplayName;
}
```